# Sails JS - Sessions

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js

Each time the page is reloaded, I run this function:

```
init: function(req, res)
{
    console.log("Session: ");
    console.log(req.session);

    if (req.session.player_id !== undefined)
    {
        Player.getPlayer(req.session.player_id);
    }
    else
    {
        req.session.player_id = sails.uuid.v4();
        req.session.save();
        console.log("Session saved");

        Player.createPlayer(req.session.player_id);
        console.log("Creating player: " + req.session.player_id);
    }
}
```

The problem is that every time I run

```
    console.log("Session: ");
    console.log(req.session);
```

The player_id isn't there, and each time the page is reloaded, the if-statement returns false.

```
console.log("Creating player: " + req.session.player_id);
```

Returns the correct value, but I can't figure out why the session doesn't follow the user on each page reload?

Comment: 1. To compare with *undefined* you better use **!==**. 2. What does it show in `console.log(req.session.player_id);`?

Comment: 1. Thanks for the suggestion. 2. Where do you mean?

Comment: Except of `console.log(req.session);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the solution was as simple as this:

```
res.send(req.session);
```

If I add this to the end of the else-statement, the session will be stored and can be re-used.

Why it's like this, I don't know. If anyone feels like elaborating, be my guest.

Comment: Note: The property will not be stored in the session store nor available to other requests until the response is sent. From: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/sessions